# Does the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty b^{k^2}$ have a closed form?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does the following series have a closed form solution ?

$$S(b) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty b^{k^2}$$

Please point to resources, if any, that I could use to learn how to determine the above for series with a general nonlinear exponent. Thanks !

Comment: I should have pointed out that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty b^{k^2}$ is not a function of $k$, but of $b$ so you should write $S(b)$ instead of $S(k)$.

Comment: Related: [Closed form of a generating function $\sum _{n=1}^\infty x^{n^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1587853)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is $\frac{1}{2}(\theta_3(0, b) + 1)$ where $\theta_3$ is related to the [Theta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function). In particular, see the section on [Auxiliary functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function#Auxiliary_functions).

Comment: That's a «closed form» for the series only by cheating.