# Closed form of a generating function $\sum _{n=1}^\infty x^{n^2}$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, generating-functions, closed-form

I am looking for a closed form of the expression

$$F(x) =  \sum _{n=1}^\infty x^{n^2} $$

The question arose when I attempted to prove Lagrange's four square theorem via generating functions. It doesn't seem the closed form exists, but I couldnt find any confirmation in the literature.

Comment: Look up Jacobi theta function

Comment: That's very helpful, thank you very much :)

Comment: Related: [Does the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty b^{k^2}$ have a closed form?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/468187).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using parity to extend the summation to all integers, one can recognize in the resulting expression [Jacobi theta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html) $\vartheta_3(z,q)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}q^{n^2} e^{2ni z}$. More precisely, we have
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{n^2}=\frac{\vartheta_3(0,x)-1}{2}.$$